# Nested Select. Need to limit results to one per certain column value

Tags: mysql, select, nested, unique

I know the id to a row. I need to get other rows from the table that contain the same values as the selected row. In this example I need all rows that share the same pos_id and eid when I only know the id of one row. I can do that, but I also need to limit the select to only one per schedID

```
|--id--+--pos_id--+--eid--+--schedID--+|
|------+----------+-------|----------|
|-212--+----33----+--534--|-54------|
|-255--+----33----+--534--|--54------|
|-258--+----33----+--534--|--54------|
|-267--+----33----+--534--|-55------|
|-278--+----33----+--534--|--55------|
```

---

```
SELECT id FROM table 
WHERE pos_id = (SELECT pos_id FROM table WHERE id=212)
AND eid = (SELECT eid FROM table WHERE id=212)
```

How do I limit it to one per unique schedID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
      max(t.id) id, t.schedID
FROM table1 t
      INNER JOIN ( SELECT pos_id , eid FROM table1 WHERE id = 212 ) pe
                  ON t.pos_id = pe.pos_id AND t.eid = pe.eid
GROUP BY t.schedID
```

Using an`INNER JOIN` allows limiting records by pos_id and eid with just a single subquery. Grouping by schedid ensures just one record for each value of that field.

Comment: no particular reason, it could be MIN(), but you only want one per schedID so a method has to be chosen

Comment: Cool. It's crazy how every project forces you to learn a new way of doing things. Thank you for the help!!!